# Talend timestamp - Getting a zero value instead of timestamp

Tags: java, postgresql, date, timestamp, talend

I am converting string to date using a **tConvertType** component in Talend.The data(source is in String) is getting loaded when I do the date pattern yyyy-mm-dd but when I try with timestamp `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` then I am getting an error. The data from the source has the timestamp but then I am getting an error.
For Eg : I have the source as `2015-09-03 14:14:90` , since data is in string so used tconverttype and then for destination the data type is date. But if I use timestamp then I am getting an error of Unparseable date and if I change to `yyyy-mm-dd` then the data is coming as `2015-09-03 00:00:00` which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

try

```
convert(timestamp,expression)
```

i had the same problem in the past and convert fixed that

Comment: where do I add this ?

Comment: How and where do I add this ? In tconverttype ?

Comment: my datatype from the source is string but target is date datatype. cant use just timestamp as I am getting an error

Answer (score 0):

Using the type date and date format `"yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss"` it works fine

[image]

I recommand you to use date format by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and choose from the list.

Comment: I have used the above but getting an error... the source is in string and has the date 2015-09-03 14:14:14 but the target is in date datatype .. So I tried using the above timestamp but getting an error. If I simply use yyyy-mm-dd I am getting output as 2015-09-03 00:00:00

Comment: Plaese be sure that the output row have date not timestamp a type, and format is `"yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss"` just copy and past it as it's, then choose automatic conversion in the tConvertType component, it works as you can see in the picture !

Comment: Tried .. not working... input is string but output is timestamp and I used tConvert type as well as TMAP timestamp but not working.. showing unparseable date error